# Getting error in my spring boot code below. Any suggestions are welcome . Have a look-:

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In UserDto:
Getting error for this statement below-:
UserDto Class-:

```
private Set<RoleDto> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

RoleDto Class-:

```
public class RoleDto {

    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Actual error:

> Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine
> recommended JdbcType for `com.code.blogapp.payloads.RoleDto`

Tried searching in stackoverflow but found no answers. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You are using the RoleDto in an Entity. Please add the relevant parts of the entity to your question. It looks like you try to use it as a field in the entity and JPA does not know, how it should map this field to database columns. Please explain how your table(s) look like and what you want to map in your entity.

Comment: UserDto is not entity class. I have used it for API response. I have done mapping from user table to role table . This is just for API response

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Entity` annotation to your RoleDto, also pair roles set with Many To Many relationship like:

```java
         @ManyToMany
         @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
              "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
         private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

DISCLAIMER: *DTO s mainly used for data transfer, not to store data, you should double check your opinion before using DTO as entity.*